# Identify Olympic Coin with USA and Japan flags

Tags: identification, numismatics

A friend has found a coin which has been a hassle to identify. It is a silver coin, which on one side has a Japanese flag and an USA flag crossed. On the reverse side is the Olympic Rings and some writing in what I’m assuming is Japanese.

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Edit:
It weighs in at just around 5 grams.
Diameter is a little less than an inch, or the exact size of a US quarter, minus the ridges on the edge

Comment: It has no denomination (numbers telling the value) so I wonder if it is more of a medal/token than a coin. See for comparation, the 100 Yen coin commemorating the 1964 Tokyo Olympic Games, which is 4.8 g of silver (so it would be roughly equivalent): https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces9584.html This is more in line with your image: https://picclick.com/USA-General-Mills-US-Olympic-Team-Tokens-Coins-132232953411.html

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree it seems more souvenir/commemorative coin. But like you said, it doesn't have any numbers on it so I can't even pinpoint if it was from the 1964 Tokyo Games. I find it odd to have both USA flags and Japan flags on it. I think finding a translation is in order to possibly uncover more

Comment: Maybe I have been too fast to link it to the 1964 Games, but given the mix of symbols, I would say that it either commemorates USA participation in some Olympic Games that happened in Japan or Japanese participation in some Olympic Games in the USA.

Comment: The design does not match any commemorative coin / medal for the 1964 or any other of Japan's Olympics, and frankly seems too rudimentary to be an official issue. The text says "American Hall" which also seems... nonsensical. Gut feeling says this is more likely a souvenir medal possible with a user engraving from a vending machine, which is common in Japan. However such medals usually have a smooth inner circle (where the Olympic flag is on yours) with a matte outer band for engravings, and the text usually includes the date. Perhaps this is an ancient design that has long since been retired.

Comment: I showed this to a couple of Japanese friends. They felt it is most likely an old arcade token.

Comment: If my rudimentary Japanese is right, the text says "American Hole".   Which is odd.

Comment: Visually very similar to old Japanese arcade tokens. Funnily enough, Google has already indexed this post, and this is currently the only instance of an arcade coin matching this exact description.